# required=false for BooleanField generates TypeError

Tags: django

It is my understanding from documentation and other SO posts that `BooleanField` needs `required=`. When I left it out there was a syntax error in my `view.py`, where I was saving to the model. However, now that I've added `required=False` I'm getting a `TypeError`. My code:

```
class SlotFilling(models.Model):
    originator = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    empty_slot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 996, in __init__
    super(BooleanField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required'
```

Any insights into what might be happening here?

Comment: Isn't it `empty_slot = models.BooleanField(initial=True, required=False)` or something? I guess I don't remember `default` as a parameter in BooleanField.

Comment: using `initial` results in `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'`

Answer (score 1):

There is no required argument in django models you need to set `blank=False`

Check django documentacion: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank

Answer (score 0):

I realized there was an issue with the database. It was not related to the Django code.

Comment: actually, there's an error with the code as well. "required" is an invalid argument for any Django model field. Required is only used on Django forms.